# Auto resize linear layout with textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking a way to fit my `linearlayout` with my whole `textview`,
so I have so many word from my database to display it on `textview`,

this is my layout design:

First, textview display some word from database that just have not so many word.

[image]

and this is if some so many word displayed in textview

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add `wrap_content` for each of their `heights`

```
TextView1 -> layout_height="wrap_content"
TextView2 -> layout_height="wrap_content"
LinearLayout-> layout_height="wrap_content"
```

`wrap_content` is used to auto resize the layout base on its content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get multiple textviews to take up the entirety of your layout, or to have many words from your database displayed on the layout?

If you want just one or two textviews, look into the [linear layout weight property](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

```
android:weightSum 
//defines the maximum weight sum.
```

For each textview, depending on how much of the layout you want it to take up, set its

```
android:weight
```

attribute

If you are looking for multiple textviews, I would recommend just using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)